# Any EU Mention of the content of the Constitution of the United Federation of Planets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-eu, federation

Are there further mentions of this Constitution in the books, perhaps with other Guarantees?

In canon, the 7th Guarantee is mentioned in ST:TNG S04E21 that I am rewatching now, paraphrased in [*Memory Alpha*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Seventh_Guarantee):

> the Seventh Guarantee of the Constitution of the United Federation of Planets protects all Federation citizens from being compelled to give self-incriminating testimony in legal procedings. (TNG: "The Drumhead")

and the [12th Guarantee](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Twelfth_Guarantee) (which seems possibly convoluted) from ST:Voyager S07E20:

> Section seven gamma of the Twelfth Guarantee of the Constitution of the United Federation of Planets defined an artist as a "person who creates an original artistic work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_Federation_of_Planets) covers further mentions in EU/non-canon, including many details:**

- ENT novel: Last Full Measure;
- ST novel: Articles of the Federation
- DS9 - Worlds of DS9 novel: Bajor: Fragments and Omens
- Last Unicorn RPG module: The Andorians: Among the Clans
- ENT novel: Last Full Measure
- TOS novel: The Galactic Whirlpool
- TOS novel: The Entropy Effect

  The Articles required all trial records be kept and preserved.
- TOS novel: Prime Directive

  A person can only be held on contempt-of-court charges for a maximum of three months during peacetime.
- TNG novel: Losing the Peace

  Treatment of refugees by member worlds, according individuals with the rights of due process.

  Article 109, section 47 also related to the treatment of refugees, barring the use of fences or other enclosures around refugee settlements.
- Star Fleet Technical Manual

**Amendments are mentioned in:**

- FASA RPG module: The Federation
- FASA RPG - The Orions module: Book of Common Knowledge
- TNG novel: A Time to Kill [ [Eminiar Amendment](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Eminiar_Amendment) ]

**Precursor drafts:**

- TOS novel: The Prometheus Design